# Sqlite composite key not in

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a link table event_user with a composite key based on an user_id and event_id.

I have an array of (user_id, event_id) pairs in Java where i want to ensure that there doesn't exists any other (user_id, event_id) pair in the table that doesn't exists in the array.

In other tables, i just created a string of ids, and then i created the following query

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column NOT IN ( 1 , 2 , ... n)
```

However this behavior with NOT IN can not be achieved with multiple columns.
How can achieve that using Java and sqlite efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BobMalooga This does not work for a key like `1,20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, IN works only with a single column.
So you have to write out all comparisons explicitly:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE (Col1 != 1 OR Col2 != 10)
  AND (Col1 != 2 OR Col2 != 20)
  AND ...;
```

SQLite can build an index for a large IN list, but this is not done for large expressions like this.
So if the query becomes too big, you can put the IDs into a temporary table, and use a subquery to check for matching rows:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM IDsToKeep
                  WHERE IDsToKeep.Col1 = TableName.Col1
                    AND IDsToKeep.Col2 = TableName.Col2);
```

For efficiency, the temporary table should be indexed (or just be a [WITHOUT ROWID table](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) with a PK on both columns).